# xcode simulators on external drive

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, simulator

I have tried a few tutorials on the internet also from other SO questions, how to get xcode simulators on external drive.

Steps i tried:

Install Xcode

move /Library/Developers/CoreSimulator/Profiles <- this folder to /Volumes/SSD/Library/Developers/Profiles and made a simlink
`/Volumes/SSD/Library/Developers/Profiles -> /Library/Developers/CoreSimulator`

After starting xcode it is starting to "verify the ios 12.4 simulator" and then it starts flawless. After then, when i try to start the simulator for example 13.5 that is shipped default with xcode if i'm not wrong, it is start fine. But when i try 12.4 it says some weird error that connection interrupted or something like that, but when i try to boot it via command line:

```
xcrun simctl boot E2228AB7-8B64-4771-86AB-1341A4FB8EDD
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
Invalid request: Failed to load requested runtime bundle (file:///Volumes/SSD/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS%2012.4.simruntime/).
Invalid argument
Underlying error (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
    Malformed bundle does not contain an identifier at /Volumes/SSD/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 12.4.simruntime
    Invalid argument
```